# redirecting to external website causes "International Targeting | no return tags” errors in Google Search console

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, internationalization, hreflang

I have a website for an app, in `www.myapp.com/get/` i've put a `php` redirect to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app` via

```
header('Location: ' . $location);
```

Now, because Google Play has International Targeting, Google Search console complains I have "no return tags".
I see about 50 of these errors (1 per language):

- Originating URL: `/get/`
- Alternate URL:
  `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app&amp;hl=af`
- Error: No return tags

How can I avoid these false-positives?
Should I change my redirect code?

Comment: Where is Google getting the idea that these URLs have international targeting?    You usually tell Google that with `hreflang` meta.    However, because these redirects, you can't be using `hreflag` meta.   The other possibility is that you have these URLs marked as international in your sitemap.   However, you shouldn't have redirecting URLs in your sitemap, so I doubt that is the case either.

Comment: the google play website contains a list of links with `hreflang` per language, I think google complains non of these links point back to `www.myapp.com/get/`, obviously it shouldn't, Google play isn't aware that my site redirects to it.